# How do I run compile and run a c file on an AWS EC2 Linux Instance?

Tags: c, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run an executable compiled from a c file on an AWS EC2 Linux Instance and when i try to run the executable I get a bash: command not found error and cant figure out why, below is my terminal commands.

```
`[ec2-user@ip-172-31-7-57 ~]$ gcc server.c -o server
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-7-57 ~]$ ls
server  server.c  test
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-7-57 ~]$ server 51717
-bash: server: command not found
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-7-57 ~]$ `
```

The only install I have run is

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

inorder to install gcc for compilation. Am I missing an install here?

Comment: More detailed help here if you are new to bash: https://devconnected.com/command-not-found-in-bash-fixed/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike windows systems, Linux systems don't look in the current directory by default when looking for a program to run.  You need to give the path to the executable.

```
./server 51717
```

Comment: @MatthewRinne Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.